# Limits question when x tends to infinity.

Tags: limits

If $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x+1}-ax-b\right)=2$, then $a$, $b$ are

I was able to reach till this step

$\lim_{x\to \infty} x(1-a)  - (a+b) = 2.$

I am stuck after this step.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2-1}{x+1}-ax-b=2&\iff\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-a)x-b-1=2\\&\iff\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-a)x-b-3=0\end{align}and therefore $a=1$ and $b=-3$.

Comment: How is a = 1?  Is 0*infinity = 0?

Comment: @RajeshR No. If $a=1$, then your limit is just $\lim_{x\to\infty}-b-3=-b-3$. Otherwise, your limit is $\infty$. But you know that the limit is $0$. Therefore, $a=1$.

Comment: When a=1, it will be lim x*(0) with x tending to infinity. So it's like infinity*0 right ?

Comment: @RajeshR No, it is not. If $a=1$, then your function is constant and therefore the limit is that constant. It's as simple as that.

Comment: You are confusing the limit of something that tends to 0 times somwthing that tends to infinity. That is indeed an indetermination. However, for a=1, you have a plain 0. Anything times that will ALWAYS be 0, because it's not something that tends to 0 but an actual 0

Answer (score 1):

It is given

$$\frac{x^2-1}{x+1}-ax-b=\frac{(1-a)x^2-(a+b)x-(b+1)}{x+1}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}2$$

so it must be that the numerator is actually a linear polynomial (otherwise the limit would be $\;\pm\infty\;$), and then the linear coefficients in both the numerator and denominator must be such that their quotient in $\;2\;$ , so...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$, from there should be able to find $a$ and $b$.